# Rails: How do I create a controller for a has_many :through using a join model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models "Stores" and "Vendors". I created a separate join model called "Partnerships" so a store can have many vendors and the Vendor can have many stores. When the user is logged in they are affiliated to either a store or vendor. I want them to be able to create partnerships. I think I have the model down based on my research, but I can't seem to get the controller right. Most of the online examples only show the models not the controller.

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :industry, :name
  has_many :users
  has_many :workorders
  has_many :locations
  has_many :partnerships
  has_many :vendors, :through => :partnerships

   class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :industry, :name
      has_many :users
      has_many :workorders
      has_many :locations
      has_many :partnerships
      has_many :stores, :through => :partnerships

class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :vendor
  attr_accessible :store_id, :vendor_id, :store, :vendor
```

This is my current partnerships_controller#new where I get a type mismatch error during my test.

```
if params[:store_id] 
    @store = Store.where(:id => params[:store_id])
    @partnership = Partnership.new(store: @store)
  else
    flash[:error] = "Store partnership required"
  end
```

Here is my new.html.erb for Partnerships:

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
  Not found.
<% else %>
  <% if current_user.affiliation == 'Vendor' %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1> <%= @store.name %></h1>
  </div>
  <% else %>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1> <%= @vendor.name %></h1>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My User model includes an affiliation field that is either "Store" or "Vendor" and also a company_id field.

What would my controller look like to create a new partnership if I am a user whose affiliation = 'Store'? Would I do it in the partnership controller?

Comment: It may just be me, but I believe that when doing your logical database which in this case is your models. I noticed that you have a `many-to-many` relationship between `User` and `Vendor`. This cannot be good database design. As I've always known that when you have a `many-to-many` association you have to resolve this form of cardinality.

Comment: Would it make more sense then to combine the Stores and Vendors into one model called 'Companies'? That model could have a 'type' field that was either Store or Vendor. This would allow each company to have many users and a user would belong_to a company. Thanks for your input.

Comment: That does sound much better, and your relation is correct with regards to a Company and User.